# How to limit number of Months in SAS

Tags: sas, radix, proc, proc-sql

I have one column name "month" which has 31 months

what I want to do is I want to limit the number of months

for example:- Current Month followed by two future months and 3 previous months followed by current month

Like if the current month is April then it has to show something like

FEb-MAR-APR(Current month)-MAY- JUN

Anyone know, How we can do it in SAS and it should change dynamically?

Current table column Month (Format dtdate9.)

01JAN2016
01FEB2016
01MAR2016
01APR2016
01MAY2016
01JUN2016
01JUL2016
01AUG2016
01SEP2016
01OCT2016
01NOV2016
01DEC2016
01JAN2017
01FEB2017
01MAR2017
01APR2017
01MAY2017
01JUN2017
01JUL2017
01AUG2017
01SEP2017
01OCT2017
01NOV2017
01DEC2017
01JAN2018
01FEB2018
01MAR2018
01APR2018
01MAY2018
01JUN2018
01DEC2018

**Output:- I need two columns max date and min date: Max date will give +2 and min date will be -3  and for every current month it should change dynamically. These two columns max and min  i will use in my reporting tool SAS VA as month between min & max**

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please add an example of your source table and how you want the final table to look like.

Comment: In addition to example of the data you HAVE and WANT, please add the code you have tried.  Seeing your approach to the problem will help others help you.

Comment: Question Edited, please check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `INTNX()` function to get a specific data range (increment or decrement)

**Data:**

```
data have;
input date ;
informat date date9.;
datalines;
01NOV2017 
01DEC2017 
01JAN2018 
01FEB2018 
01MAR2018 
01APR2018 
01MAY2018 
01JUN2018 
;
run;
```

**Solution:**

```
proc sql;
create table want as
select 
date format=date9. ,
intnx('month',date,-3) as min_date format=date9.,
intnx('month',date,+2) as max_date format=date9.
from have;
quit;
```

**Output:**

```
date=01NOV2017 min_date=01AUG2017 max_date=01JAN2018
date=01DEC2017 min_date=01SEP2017 max_date=01FEB2018
date=01JAN2018 min_date=01OCT2017 max_date=01MAR2018
date=01FEB2018 min_date=01NOV2017 max_date=01APR2018
date=01MAR2018 min_date=01DEC2017 max_date=01MAY2018
date=01APR2018 min_date=01JAN2018 max_date=01JUN2018
date=01MAY2018 min_date=01FEB2018 max_date=01JUL2018
date=01JUN2018 min_date=01MAR2018 max_date=01AUG2018
```

Comment: You can also do the similar thing in SAS VA using  calculated fields in VA Report Designer.

Comment: ya, I did but my team lead wants to do it in data query.

Comment: I did it like this way But it is giving error'data clean1_data;

set stag0(rename=(metric_month=month_dt));
metric_month=put(month_dt, date9.);
drop month_dt;

run;

proc sql;
create table want as
select month_dt format=date9.,
intnx('month',metric_month,-3) as min_date format=date9.,
intnx('month',metricmonth,+2) as max_date format=date9.
from clean1_data;
quit;'

Comment: ERROR: Function INTNX requires a numeric expression as argument 2.
 ERROR: Character expression requires a character format.

Comment: What is the data type for metric_month? run: `proc sql; describe table stage0; quit;`

Comment: metric_month Char 15 $15. $15. metric_month

Comment: you have to convert it to date or user another column, try `input(metric_month,anydtdte20.)`

Comment: intnx('month',input(metric_month,anydtdte20.),-3) as min_date format=date9.,
intnx('month',input(metric_month,anydtdte20.),+2) as max_date format=date9.

Comment: You are welcome, if have sas VA question I will also be able to help.

Comment: Yup for sure, But when I am adding it as a filter in crosstabs like Month incl between max and min. Its not showing the data item max and min

Comment: Check the default aggregation which VA is applying to those fields. you need to filter on 1 month at a time in the cross table then use min or max aggregation and SAS VA is probably using a default avg or sum. Please create another Question for SAS VA  if it is still not working.

Comment: Hi @momo1644 i have a question for you please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50334174/how-do-i-create-a-cumulative-median-field-in-sas-va-7-4-designer

Answer (score 1):

If you have tabular data then you only need to do two steps:

1. (optional step) Sort data by date not month name `PROC SORT`
2. Use `INTCK()` function to check the interval(in month) that you want and date() which returns today's date

**Dummy Data:**

```
data have;
length date 8. month $3. ;
input date month $ ;
informat date anydtdte20.;
format date ddmmyys10.;
datalines;
01/07/2018 JUL
01/02/2018 FEB
01/03/2018 MAR
01/04/2018 APR
01/05/2018 MAY
01/06/2018 JUN
01/08/2018 AUG
01/09/2018 SEP
;
run;

proc sort data=have out=sorted; by date; run;
```

**Solution 1: Using Data Step**

```
data want;
set sorted;
diff= intck('month',date(),date);
if (diff<= 2 and diff>= -3) then output;
run;
```

**Solution 2: Using Proc SQL**

```
proc sql;
create table want2 as
select * from sorted
where intck('month',date(),date) between 2 and -3 ;
quit;
```

**Output:**

```
date=01/02/2018 month=FEB diff=-3 
date=01/03/2018 month=MAR diff=-2 
date=01/04/2018 month=APR diff=-1 
date=01/05/2018 month=MAY diff=0 
date=01/06/2018 month=JUN diff=1 
date=01/07/2018 month=JUL diff=2
```

Comment: HI thanks a lot for your reply, I want to do it in some different way like:- I will be calculating two fields max date +2 and min date.-3Then I will use this it for my  report like Month between (min & max)

Comment: That's easy, please as an example of inputs and outputs (table view) to the question and I will update my answer.

Comment: Done, Please check

Comment: I've added another answer