# How do I create a cumulative median field in SAS VA 7.4 Designer?

Tags: sas

Consider a List Table in VA 7.4 Designer. It has only two fields (Month, Median Patients). The desire is to calculate the cumulative median over the months. This cumulative median is labelled as "Median Patients". An example data with more descriptive steps is attached.

Please, take look. Note: It's easy to calculate the monthly Median Patients by just using the median function in VA 7.4 Designer (not the desire). The cumulative median is desired.

Thank you and have fun.`

```
Sample Data
-------------
Account ID  Month       #patients
----------  -------     ----------
1       Jan2017     5
2       Jan2017     3
3       Feb2017     7
4       Feb2017     6
5       Feb2017     2
6       Mar2017     4
7       Apr2017     1
8       Apr2017     10
9       Apr2017     9
10      Apr2017     3



Typical calculation in SAS VA 7.4
-----------------------------------
Monthly Median (Easy using median function)
-------------------------------------------
Month       Median Patients
---------   ---------------     
Jan2017     4       ( 5+3 ) /2
Feb2017     6       middle of ( 2,6,7 )
Mar2017     4       
Apr2017     6       middle of ( 1,3,9,10 )  = (3+9)/2 = 6



Cumulative Monthly Median (Desired in SAS VA 7.4) Any idea how to calculate this assuming this is in a List Table with only two fields (Month and Median Patients)?
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Month       Median Patients
--------    -----------------
Jan2017     4       ( 5+3 ) /2
Feb2017     5       middle of ( 2,3,5,6,7 )     = 5
Mar2017     5       middle of (2,3,4,5,6,7 )    = (4+5) /2 = 4.5(approx. 5 when rounded)
Apr2017     5       middle of(1,2,3,3,4,5,6,7,9,10) = (4+5) /2 = 4.5(approx. 5 when rounded)
```

Comment: I don't think I'd consider questions on VA Designer to be on topic here; this is really for programming questions.  You should probably head over to [communities.sas.com](http://communities.sas.com).

Comment: Cumulative measures were simplified in 8.2 but you're using a older version. Your best bet may be tech support, which I'd advise you to use in this case. It's probably the fastest option.

Comment: @ASH,  That's easy. I will post an answer for  you soon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In VA Designer:

1. Create a date parameter called `monthyear` and assign it same format as you `Month` field,
2. In the body of your report  Create a `drop-down` & `List-Table` objects,
3. Assign the `Month` field to the `drop-down`, then go to roles tab and in the parameter box select `monthyear` ; which you just created,
4. Select the List-Table, assign Month, Patient (make sure the aggregation is median) then go to the filters tab and create advances filter using the point and click: `Month <= monthyear`
5. Now the interaction is setup, make sure when you select a date from drop down you see the correct data to calculate, monthly median will be calcualted

[image: dropdwon]

6. Remove the Month/Date field from the table then the Cumulative Median will be calculated

Comment: in Step 5: When you select a date from the drop-down you will see the median value for each previous month in the list-table below. So in step 6: if you remove the date field from the table; you will get 1 row which should be the cumulative median

Comment: let me know if you are stuck in  any of the steps.

Comment: got it thanks bro.. we have option for direct message here ?

Comment: yes, in a SO Chat room. there are two types public & gallery. In public everyone can see the chat and talk. In the gallery all can see but only approved users can talk.  I've create this room to talk: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171133/sas-visual-analytics

Comment: hi i am available in chat room

Answer (score 2):

To do this via SAS Code; I `Left Join` the segregated data to itself on `month <= month` (to calculate the cumulative median for each month).

Data:

```
data have;
 infile datalines dlm=',' dsd;
 informat Month monyy7.;
 format Month monyy7.;
 input Account_ID  Month    patients;
 datalines;
1,Jan2017,5
2,Jan2017,3
3,Feb2017, 7
4,Feb2017,6
5,Feb2017, 2
6,Mar2017 , 4
7,Apr2017,1
8,Apr2017,10
9,Apr2017, 9
10, Apr2017 ,3
;
run;
```

Cumulative Median:

```
proc sql;
create table want as 
select t1.Month , median(t2.patients) as Cumm_Median , round(median(t2.patients)) as Cumm_Median_rounded
from have as t1 left join have as t2
on t2.Month le t1.month
group by t1.month
order by t1.Month
;
quit;
```

Output:

```
 Month=JAN2017 Cumm_Median=4 Cumm_Median_rounded=4
 Month=FEB2017 Cumm_Median=5 Cumm_Median_rounded=5
 Month=MAR2017 Cumm_Median=4.5 Cumm_Median_rounded=5 
 Month=APR2017 Cumm_Median=4.5 Cumm_Median_rounded=5
```

Comment: Is this what you wanted ? or You wanted to calculate it in VA Designer?

Comment: You would need SAS 9.4+ for this to work (median function is supported at SAS 9.4+) at minimum and SAS VA only supports data step code at the moment and I think that's been added after SAS VA 7.4

Comment: SAS VA7.X  runs only on SAS 9.4, and I believe if you use `sasiola` libname  to point to an existing VA library you can run any sas code. Lets wait for ASH to confirm.

Comment: @Reeza I think 7.4 is the newest version of VA for base SAS?  At least it looks like that from the VA site (https://www.sas.com/en_us/software/visual-analytics.html).

Comment: Correct 7.4 is the latest VA, the one after it is called SAS VIYA which includes Machine Learning modules.

Comment: @momo1644 I want to calculate it on SAS VA Designer 7.4 (front end)

Comment: I will post another answer  for this.

Comment: @momo1644 hi momo can u create a chat room. I have one doubt.  thanks in advance